# Render the info of an object based on its id

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am working on an e-commerce project and I have fetched all data of my orders from the server and it looks as following :

{id:"5ahegiyag6123b", order_amount:250, customer_name:"John"}

All orders are rendered in a data table. Each one in a separate row. What I want to do is, click on any order in the table which then, renders a modal with all data of this order only considering that there is no API for fetching the data of a single order with its id. How can I achieve this? any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `onClick={() => renderModal(rowData)}` event to your `data table` row and control the modal and its data display with `renderModal` by passing selected row data to the **modal**.

The **onClick** event name may vary based on the **data table** library that you are using. Check here for [row click sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/qvo21pl5zj).